# Unrecognized escape characters in bindings with BizTalk Deployment Framework

Tags: biztalk, btdf

I'm using BTDF and the settingfilegenerator to dynamically configure the bindings.  My first binding was a SQL binding and it worked fine.  However, most of my binding settings are UNC paths and I'm getting errors when trying to apply the settings.  I have tried about every combination of quotes and doubling the backslashes to try to handle this but nothing is working.  Surprisingly I haven't been able to find anyone else with the same issue.  Any ideas?

> parsing "\Myserver\Myshare\Folder\SubFolder\inbound\Enroll\%SourceFileName%.834" - Unrecognized escape sequence \i.

Thanks for the comments.  It made me look into where it was actually failing instead of the error message.  It appears to be an issue with the the install-biztalkapplication.ps1 script.  I'm not sure the origin and if there were any changes made to this script.  I commented out this block (full block not shown) and this last line is what is causing the error.    There seem to be several versions of this file available.  I'll do some additional research and provide an update.

```
get-content -path "$btdfdeploysettingsfile" | foreach-object { 
        $line = $_
               $hashconfig.getenumerator() | foreach-object {
```

Comment: Are you trying to pre-escape them on the Excel file?  You don't need to do that.

Comment: No, I am trying to get it to work without any formatting but I have tried some pre-formatting options thinking it is a c# parser that isn't handling it correctly.  The cells are formatted <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">\\MyServer\MyPath\Folder</Data></Cell>

Comment: The thing is, file paths just work.  I use them all the time.  I never need to do anything special at all.  Does this happen when you do Preprocess BizTalk Bindings?

Comment: Which tool is giving you the error? XmlPreprocess?

Comment: Please add any additional information in the question using the [edit] link, rather than in the comments.   Can you give us a sample SettingsFileGenerator.xml file that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help to point me in the right direction.  In the end the issue was in the install-biztalkapplication.ps1 and not with BTDF directly.  I removed the bad lines and the replacement is working now.